# Calling a method to update TextViews in an activity from a service

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I have a project that is supposed to receive the current location from a location manager and then update the textviews in an activity that display those coordinates to the user. We want the location manager to be running as a service in the background. Currently even if I have the activity open, whenever the location updates and the method to update the textViews is called from the service we get a force close. I also cannot change the method to a static method because statics are incompatible with textViews. Below is the service, the method being called, and the stack trace.

method in service that is called when location changes

```
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            currentLocation = location;
            SplashActivity.historyList.add(currentLocation);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Point added",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //postpones the update until NavigatorActivity starts
            if (NavigatorStarted) {
            new NavigatorActivity().doActionFine(currentLocation);
            }
            // these lines are controversial...
            if (location.getAccuracy() > 1000 && location.hasAccuracy())
                locationManager.removeUpdates(this);                          

        }
```

methods in activity that are meant to update text views with new location either from accurate GPS signal or rough signal. Use the do action methods to call from service with Parameter of current location from LocationService

```
public void updateLocationTextViewsFine(Location currentLocation) {
    currentLatView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentLat);
    currentLonView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentLon);
    // update the textviews (labels)
    String lat = currentLocation.getLatitude() + " (accurate)";
    String lon = currentLocation.getLongitude() + " (accurate)";
    currentLatView.setText(lat);
    currentLonView.setText(lon);
}
public void updateLocationTextViewsCoarse(Location currentLocation) {
    currentLatView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentLat);
    currentLonView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentLon);
    // update the textviews (labels)
    String lat = currentLocation.getLatitude() + " (low accuracy)";
    String lon = currentLocation.getLongitude() + " (low accuracy)";
    currentLatView.setText(lat);
    currentLonView.setText(lon);
}

public  void doActionFine(Location currentLocation) {
    updateLocationTextViewsFine(currentLocation);
}


public void doActionCoarse(Location currentLocation) {
    updateLocationTextViewsCoarse(currentLocation);
}
```

New error received.

```
04-20 20:15:33.894: E/AndroidRuntime(4389): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 20:15:33.894: E/AndroidRuntime(4389): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-20 20:15:33.894: E/AndroidRuntime(4389):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1637)
04-20 20:15:33.894: E/AndroidRuntime(4389):     at com.example.UVAMapsProject.NavigatorActivity.updateLocationTextViewsFine(NavigatorActivity.java:341)
04-20 20:15:33.894: E/AndroidRuntime(4389):     at com.example.UVAMapsProject.NavigatorActivity.doActionFine(NavigatorActivity.java:360)
04-20 20:15:33.894: E/AndroidRuntime(4389):     at com.example.UVAMapsProject.LocationService$2.onLocationChanged(LocationService.java:116)
04-20 20:15:33.894: E/AndroidRuntime(4389):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:191)
04-20 20:15:33.894: E/AndroidRuntime(4389):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:124)
04-20 20:15:33.894: E/AndroidRuntime(4389):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:140)
04-20 20:15:33.894: E/AndroidRuntime(4389):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-20 20:15:33.894: E/AndroidRuntime(4389):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-20 20:15:33.894: E/AndroidRuntime(4389):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-20 20:15:33.894: E/AndroidRuntime(4389):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 20:15:33.894: E/AndroidRuntime(4389):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-20 20:15:33.894: E/AndroidRuntime(4389):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
04-20 20:15:33.894: E/AndroidRuntime(4389):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-20 20:15:33.894: E/AndroidRuntime(4389):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: and you're postponing until the activity starts? how are you doing that? waiting for onCreate? onStart? because it looks like either your views haven't been initialized or your currentLocation hasn't

Comment: We start the service at the very beginning when the first activity begins, but were postponing updating textviews until after the NavigatorActivity had been created using a boolean saying don't call the NavigatorActivity.update... unless navigatorActivityStarted == true

Comment: Our views and current location have been. When I run the application i receive a toast that says current location is initialized and is updated. That is working every time, and also I don't get the error until I am already in Navigator Activity and can see the views therefore they have to be initialized.

Comment: by initialized i mean wherever you do `currentLatView = (TextView) findViewById(whatever);` maybe you have a copy/paste error? It could render the view from XML without them being set locally

Comment: @JRaymond       see edits. I am now initializing them locally and am still getting null pointer but now on those ...

Comment: at what point in NavigatorActivity's lifecycle does navigatorActivityStarted become true? I think that the activity's methods are being called before onCreate is finished and setContentView hasn't happened yet

Comment: navigatorActivityStarted is called at the end of the onCreate. After setContentView

Answer (score 2):

This could be done using a Binder:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html

Then in the activity do it as in the example in the above article. When you are connected to the service, ask for the current location (which is saved in the Service or in Preferences). Then you give a listener to the service, that will be called.

Here some sample code. Missing implementing of Listener and LocalService class. But just to show what I meant.

```
public class BindingActivity extends Activity {
    LocalService mService;
    boolean mBound = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Bind to LocalService
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocalService.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // Unbind from the service
        if (mBound) {
            mService.removeListener(this);
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }
    }

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                IBinder service) {
            // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;

            handleLocation(mService.getCurrentLocation());
            mService.addListener(BindingActivity.this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };
}
```

When activity is finished, you remove the listener from the service before unbinding.

Comment: i'm not understanding how I will call the updateLocationTextViews() method in the activity after binding. Also, receiving error saying that  onServiceConnected and onServiceDisconnected are not overrides

Comment: Where is LocalBinder coming from?

Comment: Nevermind; when I followed your provided link I found the definition. Thanks for the excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
new NavigatorActivity().doActionFine(currentLocation);
```

Just saw this.... you're creating a New instance of the activity and calling the method on it.  this new instance is not the same activity that was created to open up your lock, this is a new activity with no lifecycle methods called.  I would definitely move to the Binder scheme like the one shown in the other answer

Comment: Used above methodology based off suggestion. Thought it seemed suspicious. Working to implement bind. Thanks!